# Unable to open UART port on Windows IoT with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I have null in the serial port after I open the SerialDevice in C# on Windows IoT Core 10 running on Raspberry Pi 3.

Here is the code:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
List<DeviceInformation> list = devices.ToList();
DeviceInformation di = list.First();
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id);
```

`serialPort` is `null`.

`di.Id` equals: `Id "\\\\?\\ACPI#BCM2836#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"  string`

`list.Count` equal `1`

Here are two records from `/api/devicemanager/devices` `GET` request related to `UART`:

```
{
  "Class": "Ports",
  "Description": "BCM283x Mini UART Serial Device",
  "ID": "ACPI\\BCM2836\\0",
  "Manufacturer": "Microsoft",
  "ParentID": "ACPI_HAL\\PNP0C08\\0",
  "ProblemCode": 0,
  "StatusCode": 25182218
},
{
  "Class": "System",
  "Description": "ARM PL011 UART Device Driver",
  "ID": "ACPI\\BCM2837\\4",
  "Manufacturer": "Microsoft",
  "ParentID": "ACPI_HAL\\PNP0C08\\0",
  "ProblemCode": 0,
  "StatusCode": 25165834
},
```

I tried both to short circuit Rx and Tx and to not shortly circuit it, it doesn't works...

**UPDATE**

If I split the given ID, I have `Invalid data` exception.

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
List<DeviceInformation> list = devices.ToList();
DeviceInformation di = list.First();

string id = "{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}";
try { serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(id); } catch(Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }
id = "\\\\?\\ACPI#BCM2836#0#";
try { serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(id); } catch(Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }
id = di.Id;
try { serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(id); } catch(Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }
if (serialPort == null) { Debug.WriteLine("No device"); return; }
```

The output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
>   The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
>   No device

Comment: It's fairly clear that the di.Id string you found is longer, i.e. includes a GUID at the end, than the ID stored in your devices record.  Perhaps it can't find the ID you're asking it to find?

Comment: You are wrong, see my update.

Comment: How am I wrong?!  "ACPI\\BCM2836\\0" != "\\\\?\\ACPI#BCM2836#0#"... lol

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505107/serialdevice-fromidasync-yields-a-null-serial-port

Comment: And this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9633593-377e-4d6f-b3a9-838de0555371/serialdevicefromidasync-always-returns-null-unless-the-serial-adapter-is-plugged-in-after-boot?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: And this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36252/windows-10-iot-core-simple-serial-sample-not-working and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=813909#p813909.  Can an admin consider moving this question to the RaspberryPi.StackExchange site?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong about "ACPI\\BCM2836\\0", it gives same exception: "The data is invalid". But the right solution actually stay in first link you provided: 'DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication"'. I will post the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Grim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393949/grim) said, the solution is here: [SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() yields a null serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505107/serialdevice-fromidasync-yields-a-null-serial-port)

It is necessary to add:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

in the `<Capabilities>` tag in `Package.appxmanifest` file.