# Where to locate portName for GetDeviceSelector(String portName)

Tags: c#, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I try to locate COM port using GetDeviceSelector() function, as I described here: [Unable to open UART port on Windows IoT with Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649437/unable-to-open-uart-port-on-windows-iot-with-raspberry-pi-3)

I see, that I can to provide port name to GetDeviceSelector() function:

```
public static System.String GetDeviceSelector(System.String portName);
```

In some examples it something like "COM0", "COM1" etc.
My question is: where I can find the documentation providing me port names?

This is what I get from device manager of Raspberry:

```
{
  "Class": "Ports",
  "Description": "BCM283x Mini UART Serial Device",
  "ID": "ACPI\\BCM2836\\0",
  "Manufacturer": "Microsoft",
  "ParentID": "ACPI_HAL\\PNP0C08\\0",
  "ProblemCode": 0,
  "StatusCode": 25182218
},
{
  "Class": "System",
  "Description": "ARM PL011 UART Device Driver",
  "ID": "ACPI\\BCM2837\\4",
  "Manufacturer": "Microsoft",
  "ParentID": "ACPI_HAL\\PNP0C08\\0",
  "ProblemCode": 0,
  "StatusCode": 25165834
},
```

This is piout of the plate:

[image: Raspberry 3 Pi pinout]
What the way to know the port name? In other words - what the algorithm to get the name of the required port?

**UPDATE**

*Answering Daniel question.*
I interacting using `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice` class, in follow way:

```
DataWriter dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(_serial_port.OutputStream);
dataWriteObject.WriteByte(0xF0);
await dataWriteObject.StoreAsync();

DataReader dataReaderObject = new DataReader(_serial_port.InputStream);
await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(1);
byte resp = dataReaderObject.ReadByte();
```

I know that COM is only for serial devices, currently I need just serial devices.

Comment: COM(n) are only used for serial ports.. how are you interfacing with the device?

Comment: See update in the question.

Comment: so you're just looking for a list of all serial port names currently connected?

Comment: Yes. But I want their names as in accepted in GetDeviceSelector(System.String portName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM port name seems not functional on Windows IoT Core. From this document: [Configuration of COM Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/configuration-of-com-ports), Ntddser.h etc. essential files are not available on Windows IoT Core(you can search it).

More references: "[Using Serial.sys and Serenum.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/using-serial-sys-and-serenum-sys)" "[COM Port Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/com-port-database)"

If you want to find a specified serial device on-board, it is suggested to use "UART0" in the `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector` API.

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");
```

Refer to "[Raspberry Pi 2 & 3 Pin Mappings - Serial UART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi#serial-uart)"

Related issue: "[Serial Port support for Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18023)"